# Issues with R labels not matching up sorted points

Tags: r, plot, label

I have been working on replicating a social science paper that examines support for gay marriage in the states. I am working with a dataframe (named doofus for my own amusement) that has state abbreviations, opinion estimates, and a factor level variable that specifies support as low, high, or medium (based on my categorization).

```
plot(doofus$statepred,col=doofus$supportcat,type="p",xlab="States",
ylab="Gay Marriage Support",main="Replicating Lax and Phillips",ylim=c(0,60),pch=20,cex=1.8,xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=1:51,labels=doofus$sstate,las=2,grid())
```

[image]

I like this graph just fine, but I thought it would be great to give them all labels as it would be a bit tedious for the reader to look down at the x axis and over. So I add this little line of code afterwards using the calibrate package in R:

```
text(x=doofus$sstate,y=doofus$statepred,labels=doofus$sstate)
```

I get this:

[image]

The data was originally in alphabetical order, but I sorted it by predicted value for a more clean visualization. Why are my data labels not lining up correctly? Thoughts?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. Try this ;`text(x=reorder(doofus$sstate,doofus$statepred),y=doofus$statepred,labels=doofus$sstate)`

Comment: Both of these work! But why if I have already sorted the dataframe did the text option default to the original data positions?

Comment: The 2 solutions change the default order of factor levels. This default order is used generally by plot routines in R.